# Truncate during Select deadlock - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, data-warehouse, truncate

We use a SQL Server 2005 database. Some datawarehouse tables are TRUNCATEd and reloaded every day. We run into deadlock issues when a user is running a SELECT statement against that same table.

Scenario

1. User runs report (SELECT statement).
2. TRUNCATE is executed against the table used in the above SELECT.
3. TRUNCATE receives a hard block from the SELECT statement. The SELECT statement is SUSPENDED immediately. This creates an infinite deadlock.

Does anyone have a detailed explanation on the SQL Server mechanics? Also, is there a work around?

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite deadlock"? Deadlock should be detected and rolled back by the deadlock monitor. Are you receiving a deadlock victim error? Or are you just talking about blocking? If so please show the output of the blocking DMVs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction isolation levels .

```
Set transactin isolation level read uncommitted

<query>|
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is hard to give specific advice. You'd need to look at the exact queries and what locks they take.

Here's some general advice: Run the `TRUNCATE` with `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW` to not impact reporting queries. Just retry the statement with a small delay.

You can also pick `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH` to kill the reporting query and prioritize the truncate.

You could also retry 10 times with `LOW`, then force it through with `HIGH`.

Note, that `TRUNCATE` is fully transacted and can be rolled back. Retry is safe.

Comment: I think this is really close.  How can I simulate a test though?  Currently, I am BEGIN TRANSACTION T1; SELECT * FROM table;  Then before ending the transaction, I will execute the TRUNCATE table.  This does not always cause a lot.  Any ideas how I can simulate this?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` alone should never deadlock because it takes a single Sch-M lock. A transaction with only one lock can never deadlock (I think). Here's a deadlock: http://pastebin.com/K8RN8EpZ This is not exactly your scenario, but you can use it to test the deadlock priority.